# Check existing data in firebase without be auth like in sign up step

Tags: flutter, dart, authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I currently creating a flutter app with sign up feature and I want to avoid spamming account so I setted up a phone verification to send a code by sms and fill it into the app when signing up (through twilio api). But I want to check before sending the sms if the phone number is already registred in my firestore collection(auth == null). I heard about firebase rules but I don't really know how to build it to be security compliant. I tried to use linkWithCredential but didn't seem to work. If anyone would have any advices for me ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can write a [cloud function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) to check your database if the phone number exists and return the result to the client.

Answer (score 0):

You can login anonymously in order to have an access to the firebase database.
Also, you can provide custom rules for each collection, so for example, your collection can have free access if you want, but don't do it, use anonymously login instead.